# Clearing data in the bottom sheet of BackDropScaffold

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Good day! My code is like this:

```
FirstSomeScreen() {
    BackDropScaffold (
        ...
        backLayerContent = { ... }
        frontLayerContent = { SecondSomeScreen() }
    )
}
```

SecondSomeScreen has its own ViewModel. The problem is that if you enter some data into the fields in this bottom sheet, then when you close and reopen it, the data will not be cleared. Question: How can I clear all data in SecondSomeScreen when closing the bottom sheet in BackDropScaffold?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your scaffold state is you can call a function from `viewModel` to clean all fields like so for example:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun BackdropScaffoldExample(vm:YourViewModel) {
    val scaffoldState = rememberBackdropScaffoldState(BackdropValue.Concealed)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LaunchedEffect(scaffoldState.isRevealed) {
        if (scaffoldState.isRevealed) {
            vm.functionOnReveal()
        } else {
            vm.functionOnConceal()
        }
    }

    BackdropScaffold(
        appBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text("Backdrop Example") },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        scope.launch {
                            if (scaffoldState.isConcealed) {
                                scaffoldState.reveal()
                            } else {
                                scaffoldState.conceal()
                            }
                        }
                    }) {
                        Icon(Icons.Default.Menu, contentDescription = "Menu")
                    }
                }
            )
        },
        backLayerContent = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text("Back Layer")
            }
        },
        frontLayerContent = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text("Front Layer")
            }
        },
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState
    )
}
```

Comment: You didn't read the condition and code in the question correctly. It said that FirstSomeScreen() has a BackDropScaffold in which SecondSomeScreen() is in the frontLayerContent field. This SecondSomeScreen() has its own ViewModel.

Comment: My answer is correct obviously you should instantiate the second viewModel in BackdropScaffoldExample so you can call the action `vm.functionOnReveal()` and pass the `viewModel` to the `SecondSomeScreen` to handle the rest... Or even better follow the unidirectional approach.